# JUnit 5 parallel Execution: Too few threads

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit5

I've read https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-parallel-execution and tried to setup parallel execution of my test cases.
**My goal was to run test classes in parallel**, but the test methods of each class sequential. I have got about 2-3 dozen of test classes, so executing the classes in parallel should be possible...

My junit-platform.properties contains the following lines:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism = 20
```

**The Problem**

As I can see in Eclipse debug mode, my tests actually run in parallel, **but just with 2-3 threads**. (My CPU has 8 cores, by the way.) My goal was to have about 20 threads, since I am using external resources (i. e. a REST service), which takes quite a while to respond.

Additionally to the above configuration, I've tried

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = same_thread
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.classes.default = concurrent
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.strategy = dynamic
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.config.dynamic.factor = 30
```

, but without success either (i.e. I've had just 2-3 threads).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

It seems that eventually 20 threads get actually spawned, but that takes 40s to get 10 threads, 90s to get all 20 threads. Why can't JUnit spawn all of them at the start?